# Can I set foreign key using string in mysql 5.1?

Tags: string, foreign-keys, alter-table, mysql-5.1

I have following two tables,

book table

```
    BOOK_ID VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    AUTHOR_ID VARCHAR(25)
```

author table

```
    AUTHOR_ID VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

I would like to set foreign key AUTHOR_ID from book table to connect author table.But I received the following error;

```
     MySQL Error Number 1005
```

I use primary key and foreign key to `INTEGER` data type for both tables then the error does not occur.Can I use foreign key using `string` data type in mysql 5.1 (InnoDB)? First I create my database without foreign keys. And I also alter my databases with this statement, it comes from mysql query browser;

```
ALTER TABLE `millionaire_db`.`book` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_book_1` FOREIGN  KEY`FK_book_1` (`AUTHOR_ID`) REFERENCES `author` (`AUTHOR_ID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Please show us the actual statements you ran.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pls check my post